# How can I activate burn effect on ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: unity, 13.10, compiz, effects

I saw on youtube that there is an effect that makes the windows catch fire when closing.

Here is the link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1LUM6cI32rk

But I could not make this effect work in 13.10.
Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Please provide a link to the video.

Comment: I know the Compiz settings manager!
I use it.

Comment: In the video the guy uses ubuntu 12.10

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1LUM6cI32rk

Comment: @wilf provided right solution I also forgot to tick fusion-plugins-extra. It works great, thank you also for this post.

Comment: @JohnyD. - are you using 13.10? Pity if your not, it would be interesting to try some of those effects....

Comment: I'm using 12.04 I've got all of those effects installed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem there is probably to do with one package he mentioned - here is a screenshot of that video, using Compiz's Annotate feature:
[image: compiz-fusion-plugins-extra]

This [`compiz-fusion-plugins-extra`](https://launchpad.net/compizfusion-plugins-extra) package was last supported in the `precise` 12.04 release - there is no release currently for 13.10. This is the problem. So instead of the available effects list looking like this, as in the guy's video on 12.04:
[image: large list of effect]

It looks like this, as this is 13.10, as that package cannot be installed:
[image: small list of effects]

It may be some-over package, or the available version of other packages that is the problem. It probably isn't an effects problem, as there is the FirePaint plugin:
[image: ?]

That said, you could download and install the `.deb` file from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/compiz-fusion-plugins-extra). It only depends on `compiz-plugins-extra`.

But that is probably not a good idea, as that is for another older release of Ubuntu, for an older version of unity + compiz . Considering with the standard compiz install, and some small-ish modification, I have had to purge & reinstall `compiz*` *twice*, I don't think I'll try it.